# Can't export functions in C++ Builder 64-bit DLL

Tags: c++, dll, 64-bit, c++builder

I'm working with C++ Builder XE4, trying to create a 64-bit DLL with some exported functions.

Here's some test code:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

int WINAPI DllEntryPoint(HINSTANCE hinst, unsigned long reason, void* lpReserved)
{
   return 1;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall void Test()
{
   // do smth
}
```

I create two DLLs, one with the target platform of 32-bit, the other - with the target platform of 64-bit, then check both DLLs with impdef.exe.

With the 32-bit DLL all is ok and I see this in cmd:

```
EXPORTS
Test
___CPPdebugHook
```

With the 64-bit DLL all I see is:

```
EXPORTS
```

What can be the reason for that and what is the right way to create a 64-bit DLL in Embarcadero c++?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dll has no problem. use [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) (depends.exe) instead impdef.exe to view exported functions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm able to see the exported function  with the dependency walker, tho both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the program give me the following errors while opening my dll:  
Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.  
Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Don't worry about that errors. They are not important issues. I have seen them even on VC++ dlls.

Comment: I have the same problem, which does not allow me to debug a dll! how can I force this inclusion in x64 dlls? I have several dlls that I created the same way. Some projects have created this variable (CPPdebugHook) and other projects do not create.